# Inserting text while iterating by character

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm going through a text character by character.

With this Sub.

Believe me it works.

```
Sub Recorrida2()

prepararVariables

   For Each parrf In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        DoEvents
        Dim c As Integer
        c = 1
               For Each car In parrf.Range.Characters
                     If cargaAPatron(car) Then
                     MsgBox "lleno ok"
                     Selection.TypeText ("ENTER")
                     lleno = 1
                     End If

                Next 'parrafo
Next

End Sub
```

My problem is that I want to insert a text when I detect a pattern.

This way it does not work

```
Selection.TypeText ("ENTER")
```

Because it inserts the "ENTER" at the beginning of the text, instead of inserting it in the place of detection.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to work with `.Selection`, this way will replace the selection.

Comment: just add `car.Select` before the `Selection.TypeText ("ENTER")`

Comment: @Sorceri I think he would then need `Selection.TypeText car & ("ENTER")` Then an `Exit For`

Comment: @dwirony  I wasn't to sure as "in the place of detection." wasn't very clear to me.  But if wishes to keep the char then you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word's Character object is also a Range object. So the following should work:

```
 car.InsertParagraphAfter
```

Generally, working with the Selection object should be avoided when automating Word. There are a very few things for which it's necessary, but writing text to a document is not one of them...

If, instead, the paragraph mark should be inserted a number of characters before the target Range (car), you can extend the start of the Range using the MoveStart method:

```
 car.MoveStart wdCharacter, -n
 car.InsertParagraphBefore
```

Where n is the number of characters you want to go backwards.